# Rails select tag with unique values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

In the view I get an array of model objects: @tasks. Task belongs to project which belongs to company. For my view I want to create select tag with uniq organization's name options. This is my currrent code:

```
 <%= select_tag :organization, options_for_select(@valid_tasks.collect{|t| [ t.project.organisation.name, t.project.organisation.name ]}),include_blank: "", :onchange => "filterTable(this, 'Organization', 'taskInformation')", class: 'form-control pull-right' %>
```

It works but it displays all organizations' names, so I have a lot of duplicates.

@valid_tasks is an array of model objects model, it is created by function:

```
relevantTasks = []
        userCards.each do |card|
            task = Task.find_by trello_id: card['shortLink']
            if task && task.name && valid_task_name(task.name) && task.label && task.list  && (task.list.upcase != "PRODUCTION") 
                if task.project_id
                    relevantTasks << task
                end
            end 
        end
return relevantTasks
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you defined `@valid_tasks`?

Comment: userCards is hash with cards and id for every each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the select tag, I think you can just call `.uniq` on the array object:

```
<%= select_tag :organization, options_for_select(@valid_tasks.map {|t| [ t.project.organisation.name, t.project.organisation.name ]}.uniq), include_blank: "", :onchange => "filterTable(this, 'Organization', 'taskInformation')", class: 'form-control pull-right' %>
```

You can also improve the function with the following:

```
userCards.map do |card|
  task = Task.find_by(trello_id: card['shortLink'])
  task if task && task.name && valid_task_name(task.name) && task.label && task.list && (task.list.upcase != "PRODUCTION") && task.project_id
end.compact
```

Notice how I am removing `relevantTasks` as `.map` already returns an array.

I don't know how your codebase looks but I'd also move the `valid_task_name(task.name)` to a class method, as such:

```
class Task
  # ...more code

  def has_valid_name?
    # Perform task's name validation here
    # and return true or false
  end

  # ...more code 
end
```

which will allow you to call `task.has_valid_name?`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is you must filter the data in your controller or in model. You can use ruby `uniq` method to filter array.

```
<%= select_tag :organization, options_for_select(@valid_tasks.uniq! {|t| t.project.organisation.name}.collect{|t| [ t.project.organisation.name, t.project.organisation.name ]}),include_blank: "", :onchange => "filterTable(this, 'Organization', 'taskInformation')", class: 'form-control pull-right' %>
```